# Custom fields: dropdown values depending on other custom field value

Tags: custom-field, dropdown

i have custom fields like this:

- "country" - values: "USA", "Russia", "China"
- "city" - values: "Chicago", "Moscow", "Beijing"

I want when user in custom field "country" choose value "USA" after that in custom field "city" show only "chicago". Is it possible? And how can I do this?

Comment: How are "city" and "country" associated in the software?

Comment: city is a part of country if I understod your question.

Comment: Well, yes. I know that. If I don't know what country a city is in I can look it up, but _how does the software know_? Software doesn't think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by using AJAX.

The following links are containing more information about AJAX and implementation in WordPress:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX

> Ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML) is a technology that allows a web page to perform actions or update dynamically, without completely reloading

- http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

> This article, aimed at plugin developers, describes how to add Ajax

- http://wpmu.org/how-to-use-ajax-with-php-on-your-wp-site-without-a-plugin/

> When using WordPress as a CMS, situations often arise where you need to display, add or update content on your WP site without turning to plugins. While bolting in some PHP alone can do the job, nothing is more seamless that the magic of jQuery’s AJAX